# "binary was not built with debug information " warning meaning in mfc application?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, media-player

I am getting the following **Warning** when i run my Windows Application(MFC) in Windows 7.

`'XXX.exe': Loaded 'C:\2010\Debug\bin\plugins\control\libhotkeys_plugin.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.`

Please Help Me out.Thank You

Comment: Maybe it was built in "release" mode?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It seems that your binary was build in Release mode

Now there are two ways which you can follow....

- build the binary with "Debug" configuration
- change the project settings so that a Program Database file (PDB) is generated in the release mode.

  Now you can generate PDB from the property window...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do this in Visual Studio 2015?  When I click on project properties, I get a much different winow and don't see configuration properties.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 20):

If your project is already in **Debug mode**. Please check **Advanced** Build Settings Dialog Box in **Build** tab of project.

Make sure that **Debug Info** is not set to none
[image]
Reference:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27307748/2073920)

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&k=k%28cs.AdvancedBuildSettings%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29&rd=true)

Answer (score 5):

Another possible way you can see this error is if you're attempting to debug native code (C++) from managed code (C#) and the manage code's csproj is set to **Native Only** debugging. To fix it:

1. Right click your csproj in VS and choose **Properties**
2. On the **Debug** tab, set the **Debugger type - Application process:** to *Mixed (Managed and Native)*

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2010 :
**Project Properties >> Configuration Properties >> Linker >> Debugging >> Generate Debug Info** : *Set it as "Yes"*

In VS 2015 :
**Project Properties >> Configuration Properties >> Linker >> Debugging >> Generate Debug Info** : Set it as "true"

Answer (score 1):

If you sure that there is no problem. You may also check application pool **physical path**, because sometimes path is keeping local path hence it involves different version.

For Instance in IIS,

->Sites

->>Specified site

->>>Look the at right window

->>>>Look at the Actions Button and click the Basic Settings

->>>>>Check the physical path