# Binary was not built with debug information in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008, dll, dllimport

Though the project builds without any error, when I debug the project for starting new instance, the following error is dispayed:

> winpeshl.exe - Application Error
>
> The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000142). Click OK
>   to terminate the application.

And the debug output panel displays the following:

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxfs.dll', Binary was not built with debug
>   information.

`msxfs.dll` is an external dll file which I have added to the project and also copied to C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: You should download the debug version of the DLL or build a debug version yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a release version of msxfs.dll in your program which is in debug mode.(It's my guess, Please check your project settings to verify the same).
If it is the case then you can download/build it yourself in debug version mode of msxfs.dll. or else you can change your project settings to release mode.
**Read**
[To Generate release Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx)
[To Generate Debug Build with Debug Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721864/binary-was-not-built-with-debug-information-warning-meaning-in-mfc-applicatio)