# Visual Studio breakpoints not hitting

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

I have a solution with multiple projects that working together to form a program for my company. When I put a breakpoint into the main project it shows a filled red dot meaning that it will be hit. However, The breakpoints that I'm putting into the other projects are a hollow red dot with a warning that the breakpoint will not be hit. How do I handle this?

Comment: I'm afraid this is a whole debugging exercise and likely not to fit well with the Q&A format of SO. (i.e., be prepared for downvotes.) There are just so many reasons it can happen. What are the other projects? Applications or just libraries? If applications, are they in fact running? Are they all built in Debug mode? Did it compile with the latest code?

Comment: I am working with someone else's code so I'll try my best to answer your questions. the other applications are complete projects and they are in fact running. My initial application depends on them. In the Tools > Debug > Modules I see my initial application with Symbols loaded but the other ones have Binary was not built with debug information.

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21757048/1223642