# How can I debug an assembly that was assigned a strong name by StrongNamer?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, strongname

I have two projects (C# .NET Framework):

- A library
- A console client that references the library

I have the dll + pdb for both projects, so without strong names, I can debug both projects. However, when I use [StrongNamer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StrongNamer/) to add strong names, I cannot debug the library. When I check the Debug Modules, it says "Binary was not built with debug information."

How can I debug this assembly while using StrongNamer?

Comment: could you provide some code about strongNamer?

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT, what code do you want to see? I don't think it has anything to do with the code I've written. "Strong Namer will automatically add strong names to referenced assemblies which do not already have a strong name." ([source](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StrongNamer/))

Comment: based on my research, you can refer to the second answer in the link [Binary was not built with debug information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30364807/11507778).

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT thanks, but that doesn't help. The binary is built with debug information. As I said, I can debug the library fine - just not once I add a reference to StrongNamer.