# Error when Debbuging in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I get the following error when I try to debug my program:

```
'Project1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvcompiler.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
```

I have debugged it previously with no problem. I just added a piece of code, but got no error compiling.

The program doesn't even start. I have all the .dll of all the libraries I use.

Comment: That's not an error it's a warning issued by the debugger. It just means you're using an executable module that was not built with any debug infomation. Consider it lives in Windows\System32 it's likely a DLL you don't own and is not something you should be concerned about. If your application does not start it is because of reasons you have not provided any context for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your answer is already on SO:

- [Binary was not built with debug information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757048/binary-was-not-built-with-debug-information)
- ["binary was not built with debug information " warning meaning in mfc application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721864/binary-was-not-built-with-debug-information-warning-meaning-in-mfc-applicatio)

From your output I think that your program is compiling and starting fine. You have nvcompiler.dll as one of your dependencies and the output is simply telling you that you're running in debug but don't have the debug version of nvcompiler.

We need more info to help further...